# Rails/CSS: How do I make a gallery of images of different widths?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, image

I have many images of the same height but different widths. I want a text caption below each image. How do I structure my gallery in Rails (incl. CSS, jQuery, Ruby etc.) such that I get rows of images collating together, so that there aren't any large spaces in between images?

Right now, I am using Bootstrap with fixed column sizes, so there is a lot of space wasted. I want each image wrapper to shrink to its image's width and for the images to be in rows with little space in between images.

I also need a text caption below each image. The wrapper containing each image and caption should have width equal to the minimum of the caption width and the image width.

Comment: Can you show your current codes ?

Comment: Without any code or markup, I would say focus on the CSS. Play with the CSS in your browser's developer tools, and focus especially on the padding and margin around your images.

Answer (score 0):

I would use CSS `float:left;` on your wrapper divs.  Have some CSS similar to this:

```
.row-div{height:325px;width:auto;}
.wrapper-div {float:left;height:320px;margin-right:5px;}
.inner-div{height:20px;margin-right:5px;}
```

But then you would need a little bit of logic (I would recommend just doing this in javascript) that determines (based on the width of each image) when to put the next image into a new .row-div and when to put it in the same row.  So you would want to write the markup dynamically.

This is the general way you'd want to do this, but it's hard to give a complete solution without more information.